Create descriptive table with custom row order and grouping
I'm trying to create a table to describe data which has multiple dichotomous columns describing whether a particular event happened or not.
Single IDs can have multiple events and there are multiple sub-types of events (described by inf_<n> and sub_inf_<n>_t<n>.
This is the code I have so far.
set.seed(123)
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
library(kableExtra)
df <- tidyr::tibble(
  id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  inf_1 = structure(factor(sample(seq(0,1), size = 10, replace = TRUE), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Unchecked", "Checked")), label = "IA"),
  inf_2 = structure(factor(rep_len(0, length.out = 10), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Unchecked", "Checked")), label = "PNEU"),
  inf_3 = structure(factor(sample(seq(0,1), size = 10, replace = TRUE), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Unchecked", "Checked")), label = "BSI"),
  inf_4 = structure(factor(sample(seq(0,1), size = 10, replace = TRUE), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Unchecked", "Checked")), label = "other"),
  sub_inf_1_t1 = structure(factor(sample(seq(0,1), size = 10, replace = TRUE), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Unchecked", "Checked")), label = "lower"),
  sub_inf_1_t2 = structure(factor(sample(seq(0,1), size = 10, replace = TRUE), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Unchecked", "Checked")), label = "upper"),
  sub_inf_1_t3 = structure(factor(c(0,0,0,1,1,0,NA,NA,0,1), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Unchecked", "Checked")), label = "other"),
)

df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~ forcats::fct_recode(.x, "No" = "Unchecked", "Yes" = "Checked"))) %>%
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(data = ., include = -id, statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)")) %>%
  kable()




Characteristic
N = 10




IA
5 / 10 (50%)


PNEU
0 / 10 (0%)


BSI
2 / 10 (20%)


other
3 / 10 (30%)


lower
5 / 10 (50%)


upper
8 / 10 (80%)


other
3 / 8 (38%)


Unknown
2



Created on 2024-12-03 with reprex v2.1.1
What I would instead like is to have main types of event ordered by frequency with other being at the end of the list and subtypes of events being shown directly under the main event type and indented. Like the following:



Characteristic
N = 10




IA
5 / 10 (50%)


 lower
5 / 10 (50%)


 upper
8 / 10 (80%)


 other
3 / 8 (38%)


 Unknown
2


BSI
2 / 10 (20%)


PNEU
0 / 10 (0%)


other
3 / 10 (30%)



Any way to do this?
Thank you.

Two options:
(1) Using modify_column_indent
df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~ forcats::fct_recode(.x, "No" = "Unchecked", "Yes" = "Checked"))) %>%
  tbl_summary(include =-id,
              statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)")) %>%
  modify_column_indent(
    columns = label, 
    rows = variable %in% c("sub_inf_1_t1", "sub_inf_1_t2", "sub_inf_1_t3"))



(2) Using bstfun::add_variable_grouping
devtools::install_github("MSKCC-Epi-Bio/bstfun")
library(bstfun)

df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~ forcats::fct_recode(.x, "No" = "Unchecked", "Yes" = "Checked"))) %>%
  tbl_summary(include = c(inf_1, starts_with("sub_inf_1"), starts_with("inf_")), 
              statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)")) %>%
  add_variable_grouping(
    "Subtype" = c("sub_inf_1_t1", "sub_inf_1_t2", "sub_inf_1_t3")
  )




Data:
Always set the seed when simulating data.
set.seed(123)

df <- tibble(
  id = 1:10,
  inf_1 = structure(factor(sample(seq(0,1), size = 10, replace = TRUE), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Unchecked", "Checked")), label = "IA"),
  inf_2 = structure(factor(rep_len(0, length.out = 10), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Unchecked", "Checked")), label = "PNEU"),
  inf_3 = structure(factor(sample(seq(0,1), size = 10, replace = TRUE), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Unchecked", "Checked")), label = "BSI"),
  inf_4 = structure(factor(sample(seq(0,1), size = 10, replace = TRUE), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Unchecked", "Checked")), label = "Other"),
  sub_inf_1_t1 = structure(factor(c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Unchecked", "Checked")), label = "lower"),
  sub_inf_1_t2 = structure(factor(c(0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Unchecked", "Checked")), label = "upper"),
  sub_inf_1_t3 = structure(factor(c(rep(0,9),NA), levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Unchecked", "Checked")), label = "other"),
)


Thank you for this solution, I'm still missing how to order by frequency though, meaning PNEU should go after BSI since there are fewer events.

That's actually complicated. May I ask whether the subtypes are mutually exclusive?

They are not unfortunately, I can have multiple types of events and subtypes.
